# Is propositional logic enough to study real analysis?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, learning

Is it necessary to study relational logic before starting real anylisis(from Bartle and Scherbert) or propositional logic enough? Also for topics like topology and differential geometry is propositional logic enough?

Comment: At least, some familiarity with quantifiers and the basic rules for them can be helpful.

Comment: May I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with my proof-checking software. It will introduce you to propositional and predicate logic along with elementary set theory in the form you are more likely to see in analysis textbooks, which can be quite different from what you will find in many logic and set theory textbooks. Visit my website at http://www.dcproof.com

Comment: Propositional logic is not enough. It's too coarse and cannot make the distinctions necessary in analysis. For example, the definitions of convergence, or of continuity, can't be stated in propositional logic, and finer distinctions such as continuity vs uniform continuity are out of the question.

Comment: Besides what's been already said, I would had been in serious trouble if I haven't had any set theory before I tried to understand topology. Also I took my analysis course at the same time when I was attending to an introduction to logic. It really helped me a lot to have already seen first-order logic when, for instance, uniform continuity was  being dealt with.